# How to solve DatePicker UnsupportedOperationException ( CalendarView does not exists for the new DatePicker)

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I am Creating a date picker dialog for post 21 android API. But My code is fetching UnsupportedOperationException Eror. My code is as follows.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(datePicker.getCalendarView().getDate());
                vdd.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

            }
        });
```

And the error is like

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CalendarView does not exists for the new DatePicker
            at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.getCalendarView(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:498)
            at android.widget.DatePicker.getCalendarView(DatePicker.java:377)
            at com.softmaker.gazi_opu.personalhealthcare.fragment.CreateVaccineSchedule$1.onClick(CreateVaccineSchedule.java:99)
```

Need suggestion. how to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check your date picker is not set to `android:datePickerMode="calendar"`, this will cause exception in post API 21.
If so, change the mode to `android:datePickerMode="spinner"` and it should work.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#getCalendarView())